# Скопировать картинку в буфер обмена C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clipboard

Как при нажатии на кнопку в окне программы поместить картинку с диска в буфер обмена?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще простого.

Для WinForms используйте

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

Clipboard.SetImage(Image.FromFile(path));
```

Для WPF используйте

```
using System.Windows;

Clipboard.SetImage(new BitmapImage(new Uri(path)));
```

---

Да, в обоих случаях вам нужно запускать эту функцию из STA-потока. Например, из UI-потока. Если это рабочий поток, вызовите на нём `.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`. У вас не получится запустить это в пуле потоков, потому что потоки из пула не являются STA-потоками.